# Subclassing `ndarray` following tutorial yields unexpected results (i.e. partial memory, some attributes are remembers others are lost)

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I think I followed the subclassing tutorial correctly. I have a very simple example. It works when I run the code once. When I rerun a cell in a Jupyter notebook, then the class breaks and it "forgets" state (well it remembers the stuff I added, it forgets that transpose I did to numpy array). See code below.

Below I implement three simple classes NamedAxis, NamedAxes, and NamedArray (yes I am aware of xarray, this is for my own learning purposes). Mostly it works fine. However, I notice something very frustrating when I rerun flip

```py
from copy import deepcopy
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import List, Dict, Union, Optional, Any, Callable, TypeVar, Generic, Type, cast, Tuple
import numpy as np, pandas as pd


@dataclass
class NamedAxis:
    # name of axis
    name: str
    # index of axis
    axis: Optional[int] = None

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name}({self.axis})'
    
    __repr__ = __str__

    def copy(self) -> 'NamedAxis':
        copy = deepcopy(self)
        return copy

    
@dataclass    
class NamedAxes:
    axes: Union[List[NamedAxis], Tuple[NamedAxis]]
    name: Optional[str] = 'NamedAxes'
    umap: Dict[str, NamedAxis] = field(default_factory=dict, init=False, repr=False)
    
    def __post_init__(self):
        # assign unique id to each axis
        for i, axis in enumerate(self.axes):
            axis.axis = i
        
        self.umap = {ax.axis: ax for ax in self.axes}

    @property
    def ndim(self):
        return len(self.axes)
    
    @property
    def anames(self):
        # names in current location
        return [str(ax.name) for ax in self.axes]
    
    @property
    def aidxs(self):
        # original location as ax.axis should never be changed
        return [int(ax.axis) for ax in self.axes]
    
    @property
    def alocs(self):
        # current location
        return list(range(len(self)))

    def __getitem__(self, key:Union[int, str, NamedAxis]) -> NamedAxis:
        # NOTE: this gets current location of axis, not original location
        if isinstance(key, int):
            return self.axes[key]
        
        # NOTE: this gets location based off original location
        elif isinstance(key, NamedAxis):
            return self.umap[key.axis]

        # NOTE: this gets location based off original location
        elif isinstance(key, str):
            for ax in self.umap.values():
                if key == ax.name:
                    return ax
                
                elif key == str(ax.axis):
                    return ax    
        else:
            raise KeyError(f'Key {key} not found in {self.name}')
        
    def __str__(self):
        _str = f'{self.name}(' + ', '.join(self.anames) + ')'
        return _str
    
    __repr__ = __str__
    
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.axes)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.axes)
    
    def copy(self):
        copy = deepcopy(self)
        copy.umap = self.umap.copy()
        return copy
    
    def index(self, key:Union[int, str, NamedAxis]):
        ax = self[key]
        return self.axes.index(ax)

    def transpose(self, *order:Union[str, int, NamedAxis]):
        # check input and convert to axes
        update_axes = [self[key] for key in order]

        # gather the axes that are not in the provided order
        needed_axes = [ax for ax in self.axes if ax not in update_axes]
        
        # the new order of axes is the updated axes followed by the needed axes
        new_order = update_axes + needed_axes
        print('NamedAxes.transpose:\t', self.name, self.axes, new_order)

        # rearrange axes according to the new order
        self.axes = new_order
        return self


a, b, c = NamedAxis('axis-a'), NamedAxis('axis-b'), NamedAxis('axis-c')
abc = NamedAxes((a, b, c))
abc




class NamedArray(np.ndarray):
    DIMS = NamedAxes([NamedAxis('axis-a'), NamedAxis('axis-b'), NamedAxis('axis-c')], name='Trajectories')
    
    def __new__(cls, arr, dims=None):
        obj = np.asarray(arr).view(cls)        
        obj.dims = (dims or cls.DIMS).copy()
        return obj
    
    def __new__(cls, arr, dims:NamedAxes=None):
        # Input array is an already formed ndarray instance
        # We first cast to be our class type
        obj = np.asarray(arr).view(cls)
        # add the new attribute to the created instance
        obj.dims = (dims or cls.DIMS).copy()      
        # Finally, we must return the newly created object:
        return obj
            
    def __array_finalize__(self, obj):
        print('finalize, dims=', getattr(obj, 'dims', None))
        print('finalize, obj=', obj)
        if obj is None: return        
        self.dims = getattr(obj, 'dims', self.DIMS.copy())

        # Ensure the indices are in the correct range
        shape = self.shape
        if len(shape) != len(self.dims):
            raise ValueError('NamedArray must have {len(self.dims)} dimensions, but got {len(shape)}.')
        
    def __array_wrap__(self, out, dims=None):
        print('In __array_wrap__:')
        print('   self is %s' % repr(self))
        print('   arr is %s' % repr(out))
        # then just call the parent
        return super().__array_wrap__(self, out, dims)
    
    
    @property
    def dim_names(self):
        return tuple(self.dims.anames)
            
    @property
    def dim_str(self):
        _str = ', '.join([f'{s} {n}' for s, n in zip(self.shape, self.dim_names)])
        return f'({_str})'
             
    def __repr__(self):
        base = super(NamedArray, self).__repr__()        
        first_line = base.split('\n')[0]
        spaces = 0
        for s in first_line:            
            if s.isdigit():
                break
            spaces += 1
        spaces = ' ' * (spaces - 1)
        return f'{base}\n{spaces}{self.dim_str}'
    

    
    def flip(self, axes:Union[str, int, NamedAxis]=None):
        # I tried transpose as well
        print(self.dims.axes)    
        # Get the order of axes indices        
        new_idxs = [self.dims.index(self.dims[ax]) for ax in axes]
        print(axes, new_idxs)

        # Transpose the NamedAxes
        self.dims.transpose(*axes)        
        print(new_idxs, self.__array_interface__['shape'])
        
        # Transpose the underlying numpy array
        self = np.transpose(self, axes=new_idxs)
        # self.transpose(*new_idxs)
        

        '''
        # NOTE: StackOverflow post edit / clarification
        I've tried this a few different ways including 
        `self.transpose()` as well as just `return np.transpose()`, 
        and trying to change the function flip to `transpose` etc. 
        This is just the version I am posting for brevity without 
        the 10 different `flip` implementations
        '''


        return self
```

So lets make some dummy data:

```py
arr = np.random.randint(0, 5, (2, 3, 4))
nar = NamedArray(arr)
nar
# (2 axis-a, 3 axis-b, 4 axis-c)

''' NOTE: flip is basically transpose, with the difference that 
`arr.transpose(1, 0, 2).transpose(1, 0, 2)` will do two transposes
but since we are using names and named indices, `nar.flip('b', 'a', 'c').flip('b', 'a', 'c')` should only do one. In other words `flip` is declarative, saying how we want the axes to be. Similar to einops / xarray
'''

nar.flip(('axis-c', 'axis-b', 'axis-a'))
# (4 axis-c, 3 axis-b, 2 axis-a)
```

So far so good. However, when I run the cell again

```py
# (2 axis-a, 3 axis-b, 4 axis-c)
nar.flip(('axis-c', 'axis-b', 'axis-a'))
# (2 axis-c, 3 axis-b, 4 axis-a)
```

I have spent way too long debugging this and I can't figure it out.

Comment: does `nar.flip` return a new array or modify `nar` itself?

Comment: @hpaulj ideally it works like `np.transpose` e.g. `np.random.randint(0, 5, (2, 3, 4)).transpose(1, 0, 2).transpose(1, 0, 2).transpose(1, 0, 2)`. I (_think_) I have tried both ways

Comment: @hpaulj would be curious to know what you think? I believe [`numpy.transpose`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html) does transpose in place `"a with its axes permuted. A view is returned whenever possible."` which to me suggests maybe the error is with handling `numpy.ndarray` `view`s, as the original data would still not be transposed, just its view?

Comment: A transpose is a `view`, a new array with shared memory,.  Not inplace

Comment: Is the `flip` in the same cell as the creation of `nar`, or is it in a separate cell? And is `nar.flip` supposed to be a mutative operation?

Comment: @user2357112 no `flip` is in a different cell than its creation. Although I suppose it should work regardless. I want it to be as close to `np.transpose` as possible. The difference is that in `arr.transpose(1, 0, 2).transpose(1, 0, 2).transpose(1, 0, 2)` will keep transposing while `nar.flip('b', 'a', 'c').flip('b', 'a', 'c').flip('b', 'a', 'c')` won't as internally it ends up mapping to `nar.transpose(1, 0, 2).transpose(0,1, 2).transpose(0,1, 2)`. `flip` is using the names to ensure the axes are in that order.

Comment: "I want it to be as close to np.transpose as possible." - so should it be non-mutative, then? Because `self.dims.transpose(*axes)` is mutative.

Comment: `self = np.transpose(self, axes=new_idxs)`, on the other hand, is non-mutative, despite assigning to `self` - the assignment just rebinds a local variable. Your `flip` is half-mutative and leaves the object in an inconsistent state.

Comment: @user2357112 please see my previous comments (also in the post). I switched to np.transpose instead of `self.transpose` (without declaring self) as part of just trying to get it to work. Is `arr.transpose(1, 0, 2).transpose(1, 0, 2).transpose(1, 0, 2)` mutative? If not then I don't want it to be mutative. I am looking for someone to help me understand.

Comment: `arr.transpose(1, 0, 2).transpose(1, 0, 2).transpose(1, 0, 2)` is non-mutative.

Comment: @user2357112 ok then I want it to be nonmutaive.

Comment: @user2357112 can you make a full answer?

Comment: @hpaulj would you be willing to make a full answer?

Answer (score 0):

## In this line you create a local variable named self. so the variable self (parameter of flip) is never modified

## Transpose the underlying numpy array

self = np.transpose(self, axes=new_idxs)

Comment: I've tried it a few different ways including `self.transpose()` as well as just `return np.transpose()` etc. This is just the version I am posting for brevity without the 10 different `flip` implementations

Answer (score 0):

```
# try this
def flip(self, axes:Union[str, int, NamedAxis]=None):
        # I tried transpose as well
        print(self.dims.axes)    
        # Get the order of axes indices        
        new_idxs = [self.dims.index(self.dims[ax]) for ax in axes]
        print(axes, new_idxs)

        # Transpose the NamedAxes
        self.dims.transpose(*axes)        
        print(new_idxs, self.__array_interface__['shape'])
        
        # Transpose the underlying numpy array
        ndarr = np.transpose(self, axes=new_idxs)
        self.shape = ndarr.shape
        # self.transpose(*new_idxs)
        

        '''
        # NOTE: StackOverflow post edit / clarification
        I've tried this a few different ways including 
        `self.transpose()` as well as just `return np.transpose()`, 
        and trying to change the function flip to `transpose` etc. 
        This is just the version I am posting for brevity without 
        the 10 different `flip` implementations
        '''
```